# Ajax in-place Editing on a dynamic mysql table

Tags: mysql, ajax, edit, inplace-editing

The title should be specific enough, but basically I have a table that is filled with data from a table in my mySQL database, and i'm trying to add a feature on my table to allow in-line edits to all but two columns, the primary key ID column, and the Status column. The only tutorials I have come across so far only show how to have all columns editable but I don't want someone accidentally messing up the primary key column. And it isn't on auto increment because it has a specific ID designated before it's imported and it skips a couple numbers. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask a more specific question, like I found this tutorial (add link) that edits all fields, but I want to exclude two columns.

Comment: sorry but the title isn't specific enough, for instance we don't know what language you are using to access that DB.., as @Jack said, maybe the tutorial links will help us help you